# Arabic references in Jabref

Tags: bibliographies, arabic, jabref

I use Jabref as my referencing manager. In the picture, one reference showed up correctly, while the other did not.

In Jabref I modified the encoding to utf-8. So I was expecting all Arabic references to appear correctly. Am I missing anything? I attached my result.

[image: output_incorrect]

### Edits

#### Update 1

I had one of my friends configure Arabic in the preamble

Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setsansfont[Mapping=text-text]{Arial}
\newcommand{\aarab}[1]{\normalsize \textarab{#1}}
\linespread{1.5}
\brokenpenalty=100
```

So I of course added `\aarab{}` command in Jabref.

#### Update 2

When I open it in Atom, both show up correctly

[image: output_correct]

#### Update 3

```
@BOOK{Al-eid2006,
title = {\aarab{حقوق المرأة في ضوء السنة النبوية} women's rights in light
of Prophetic sunnah tradition},
publisher = {Whatever},
year = {2006},
author = {Nawal Al-Eid},
owner = {TeraSoft},
timestamp = {2015.08.04}
}

@MISC{Alhazmi2015,
author = {Al-Hazmi, Fahd},
title = {\aarab{مساهمة النساء في القوى العاملة خلال الثلاثين عام الماضية في 
بعض الدول العربية} Contribution of women in work force during the
last thirty years in some Arab countries},
howpublished = {Tweet},
month = {May 16},
year = {2015},
owner = {TeraSoft},
timestamp = {2015.06.08},
url = {http://t.co/wndwo7Z5KV}
}
```

Comment: Without the underlying code, it's going to be well-nigh impossible to determine what's going on, let alone offer a fix. Please edit your posting accordingly.

Comment: what happen if you open your `.bib` file with yout latex editor?

Comment: Working with `biblatex` might be easier here. Can you give the content of the bib that is shown in the screenshot as posted code?

Comment: I tried your bib file with a simple `biblatex` setting using font Scheherazde. It works fine. You screnshot of the document suggests that the font cannot display the characters. Can you extend your code snippet so that we see the complete setup that leads to this? This is in fact what Mico was asking before.

Comment: Can you put the snippet of your code here Johannes_B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The code as requested in the comments, this is not an answer but an extended comment (code markup):**

Using `biblatex` to set up the bibliography (using an author-year style) and the Scheherazade font (from the open font library) i can see everything as expected. With Arial, i wasn't able to typeset the arabic, because my version is apparently missing those glyphs and i get empty boxes like you do.  I get them for both entries, you just for one, which is strange, because as far as i can tell (non-speaker/reader) the input is the same.

[image: reemArabicBiblatex]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @BOOK{Al-eid2006,
        title = {\aarab{حقوق المرأة في ضوء السنة النبوية} women's rights in light
    of Prophetic sunnah tradition},
    publisher = {Whatever},
    year = {2006},
    author = {Nawal Al-Eid},
}

@online{Alhazmi2015,
    author = {Al-Hazmi, Fahd},
    title = {\aarab{مساهمة النساء في القوى العاملة خلال الثلاثين عام الماضية في 
    بعض الدول العربية} Contribution of women in work force during the
last thirty years in some Arab countries},
organization = {Twitter},
date = {2015-05-16},
url = {http://t.co/wndwo7Z5KV},
origdate={2015-05-16},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Scheherazade}
%\newfontfamily\farsifont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1]{Arial}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
%\setsansfont[Mapping=text-text]{Arial}
\newcommand{\aarab}[1]{\normalsize \textarab{#1}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```